# Proximizable or proximitizable?

Tags: terminology, mathematics, orthography

Math terminology:

uniformity → uniformizable

proximity → proximizable?

or proximitizable?

Answer (score 1):

This should be asked on the maths s.e. since it deals with a very technical aspect of mathematical terminology, however:

You should use "proximizable" and "uniformizable". But according to the source below, the proximizable spaces are precisely the completely regular ones. Having established this you can just use the term "completely regular".

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UrsHbOjiR8QC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=proximizable&source=bl&ots=tufEPksxPk&sig=MCssPuSaTBSww2hDncle5XFqXnY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPr9ybzInOAhXpA8AKHS0-A4gQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=proximizable&f=false